# Как происходит составление спринта для scrum?

Tags: agile, scrum

Хочу разобраться в методологии scrum, и применять его в нашем проекте.

Насколько понял, изначально мы общаемся с клиентом, узнаем список хотелок,
которые мы записываем в наш бэклог.

Далее задачи приоритизируются продукт овнером и составляется спринт.

Вопросы:

В какой момент происходит приоритизиция продукт овнером задач из бэклога? Приоритизируются все задачи ? или только какая-то часть?

Правильно ли понимаю, что спринт составляется после приоритизации задач из бэклога ? Тогда в какой момент нужно декомпозировать задачу для спринта ? Или как определить сколько приоритетных задач из бэклога поместятся с спринт назначенной длины?

Answer (score 0):

> В какой момент происходит приоритизиция продукт овнером задач из
>   бэклога? Приоритизируются все задачи ? или только какая-то часть?

Приоритет есть у каждой задачи. Изначально он определяется при согласовании задачи с клиентом, но в процессе работы над проектом приоритеты задач могут и пересматриваться.

> Правильно ли понимаю, что спринт составляется после приоритизации
>   задач из бэклога ?

Да.

> Или как определить сколько приоритетных задач из бэклога поместятся с
>   спринт назначенной длины?

Обычно это определяется опытным путём. Каждый проект и каждая команда индивидуальны. А, каждый конкретный человек и подавно.